# Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute in LinQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I get data from a site and insert to DataTable `dt`.

```
if (checked = true)
{
    while (true)
    {
        breakIt = true;
        try
        {
            string html = browser_array[idx].FindElementByXPath("id('tabbox')").GetAttribute("outerHTML");
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);
            HtmlNodeCollection nodesMatchingXPathlop = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'tabbox_F')]/table/tbody/tr");
            if (nodesMatchingXPathlop.Count == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < nodesMatchingXPathlop.Count; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        listHeader[1].Clear();
                        HtmlNodeCollection listTD3 = nodesMatchingXPathlop[j].SelectNodes("td");
                        if (nodesMatchingXPathlop[j].SelectNodes("td").ToString() == "")
                            return;
                        if (nodesMatchingXPathlop[j].SelectNodes("td").Count == 10)
                        {
                            if (listHeader[1].Count == 0)
                                continue;
                            else
                                Insert(dt, listHeader[1]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
                }
            }
            if (breakIt)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
    }
}
```

So, this function is `Insert(DataTable dt, List<String> listHeader)`:

```
static void Insert(DataTable dt, List<String> listHeader)
{
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    string[] array = listHeader.ToArray();
    string newArray = "";
    newArray = Regex.Replace(array[1], @"\s+", " ");
    string arrayHindiCap2 = "";
    arrayHindiCap2 = Regex.Replace(array[2], @"\s+", " ").Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    string arrayHindiCap5 = "";
    arrayHindiCap5 = Regex.Replace(array[5], @"\s+", " ").Replace("&nbsp;", "");

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrayHindiCap2))
        {
            InsertCondition(arrayHindiCap2, arrayHindiCap5, newArray, listHeader, array);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrayHindiCap5))
        {
            InsertCondition(arrayHindiCap2, arrayHindiCap5, newArray, listHeader, array);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
}
```

I have a table like this:

```
Option         B0_1           Col 1            Col 2

op1            10             89
```

I will get an index of rows in DataTable when it correct with a condition.

```
static void InsertCondition(string arrayHindiCap2, string arrayHindiCap5, string newArray, List<String> listHeader, string[] array)
{
    try 
    {
        index = dt.AsEnumerable()
             .Select((rowF, idx) => new { rowF, idx })
             .Where(item =>
              GetFirstB(numB) == (item.rowF.Field<string>("B0_1") != null ? item.rowF.Field<string>("B0_1") : "") &&
              GetFirstWord(optionString) == (item.rowF.Field<string>("Option") != null ? item.rowF.Field<string>("Option") : ""))
             .Select(item => item.idx)
             .ToArray();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { throw; }
}
```

I define `GetFirstB()` and `GetFirstWord()`:

```
private static string GetFirstWord(string str)
{
    try
    {
        return string.Concat(str.Split(' ').Take(2));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
}

private static string GetFirstB(string str)
{
    try
    {
        if (str == null)
            return null;
        if (str.Equals("&nbsp;"))
            return null;
        string[] strNew;
        strNew = str.Split(' ');
        strNew = strNew.Where(c => c != "").ToArray();
        return string.Concat(strNew.FirstOrDefault());
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw; }
}
```

Following @ScottChamberlain and @PhilipKendall suggest.
I edit my code and tried debug again.

After Copy exception copies detail to clipboard it shows like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<CastIterator>d__b1`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectIterator>d__7`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at LAPSOFT.Program.InsertCondition(String arrayHindiCap2, String arrayHindiCap5, String newArray, List`1 listHeader, String[] array) in d:\lapsoft-project\CA CUOC - Copy\Program.cs:line 418
       at LAPSOFT.Program.Insert(DataTable dt, List`1 listHeader) in d:\project\CheckCopy\Program.cs:line 548
  InnerException:
```

Comment: `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` I assume that this is for debugging purposes, but in any case it should be `catch (Exception ex) { throw; }` so that you keep the stack trace correct.

Comment: What actual exception are you getting?

Comment: To add on what Phillip said, you should never do `throw ex`, you should only do `throw;` or do `throw new SomeNewException("Some Extra Info", ex);`. If you don't you loose the stack trace of the exception and it will now point at the `throw ex;` line instead of the line the exception actually happened on. Click "[Copy exception detail to clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)" and give us the full exception info.

Comment: I edited my question with you suggest and copy all details of the exception.

Comment: I think that the problem is in this line   strNew = strNew.Where(c => c != "").ToArray(); try var strNewtest = strNew.Where.....

Comment: I tried change: `var strNewClone = strNew.Where(c => c != "").ToArray();` but error still appear.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. I'd start with the two functions (just return the string as it is, see if the problem is there)

Comment: In function: `GetFirstB()` I only `return string.Concat(str.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault());` but I still error. I think error is not ` var strNewtest = strNew.Where....`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Can you resolve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe you are showing all of the relevant code.  For one thing, `InsertCondition` appears to have side effects.  For example, where is `dt` defined and is `index` a static global variable?  If so, ewwww.  More importantly, though, what is going on in the function call at the root of your stack trace: `LAPSOFT.Program.Insert`?  The name certainly is suspicious.  It sounds like it may be inserting something... possibly while iterating.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I updated my question. Seem too much code. Hope so you can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is too much invisible to us. At the same time, this is a message to you that your code is too complex. There are too many moving parts that operate in one big tangle. Try to disentangle your code by writing short functions without side effects (i.e. without reading and modifying mutable member variables, let alone global static variables).